# module holding variables, mutable vs immutable

Tags: python

Ok, here is the situation. I need a set of variables to be global and so far there was no need to ever change them. Now some situations occur when I would need to do something like:

```
from config import some_var
some_var = new_var
```

And this change should be visible in all imports after that. Now I've tried something with some dummy modules:

So in a.py

```
x = 1
y = [1]

class A():
    x = 1
    y = [1]
```

In b.py

```
from a import A, x, y

def change():
    x = 2
    y[0] = 2
    A.x = 2
    A.y = [2]
```

And main test:

```
from a import A, x, y
from b import change

print x
print A.x
print y
print A.y
change()
print x
print A.x
print y
print A.y
```

Output is:

1
1
[1]
[1]
1
2
[2]
[2]

Now I just want to be sure before doing any hasty changes because I have a lot of variables defined in config and they are used in a lot of places so if I decide to wrap them all up in a class to use them it would take some major refactoring.

Is it not possible to change a variable defined in a module in a way that will be seen in future imports? I'm guessing in my example the change in y worked because only the reference to the list is being kept, right?

Comment: Can you not just change the original file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change variables at the module level, but only if you import the module, not the variable.

When you do:

```
from a import A
```

all that happens is that a name `A` is assigned in your current namespace and set to the value of `a.A`. If you then do

```
a = 2
```

the local name is simply rebound to 2, but the value of `a.A` name remains as it is.

If however you do:

```
import a
```

`a` is now a reference to the module, and `a.A` refers to the actual variable inside that module. So now:

```
a.A = 2
```

will change the value of the variable inside that module, visible from everywhere (as long as everywhere else has also imported the module rather than a reference to the name.)

Comment: Yup. Another way to say it: a module is just another type of object in Python, and a module's globals are attributes of the module, and can be accessed and set the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of a variable at runtime does not change what is stored in the file from which the module is imported. Future imports will see what is in the file.